# Plot shows automatically

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a strange problem when plotting with `matplotlib`
Here is a sample  code

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

for i in range(100):
    plot(range(10)) 
    xlabel("x")
```

This code will pop-up 100 times a figure. It seems that show() is called automatocally.

How can I make sure that after the plots no plot-windows are showed?

Comment: This is not normal behaviour, can you provide information on the platform your using e.g your Python installation etc.

Comment: I use Spyder of Python 3.3 under windows 7. The same code dose not have this problem on other windows computers. It is so strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force it to use only one figure like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in range(100):
    ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_xlabel("x")
```

Comment: You should not `import *`